# How to read google calendar data from multiple or single calendars of different people?

Tags: php, python, google-api, google-api-client

If I  want to access multiple Google calendars of different people using google calendar who should I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the [Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php)?

Comment: yes, I found this page, but for my case it to get the event's calendars of differences people .My users using gmail account, I have store their access token refresh token ,.. in database table . and for every 4 mins I have a script to loop over all the user account to read their calendar.